# Default List view in Wordpress Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using a custom child theme of Storefront and I want the List view to be the default view for products by default. I've tried the plugin Grid/list view but it causes some issues. Is there any way I can achieve that within the functions.php ?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you really need that to be within the "funcions.php"? because there is an option in Woocommerce>>Settings>>Products that specify the default Catalog view, there you can put the grid or list as the default view, have you tried that?

Comment: Also surprised that the Grid/List View plugin is causing issues since it's authored by James Koster, who is one of the original developers of WooCommerce

Comment: I've been looking for that option but there's just nothing related to product view in my website options.The plug-in unfortunately doesn't seem to load sometimes (using incognito mode per example), the generated html is completely different and it just gets "stuck" in grid view...

Comment: I don't see an option in Woocommerce>>Settings>>Products that allows you to specify a default category view. Using version 3.4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

Go to Woocommerce.php

Switch from List to Grid and Grid to List...

Like that... I am sorry my english skills are bad :)

```
    ..........

if ( in_array( 'view', $elements ) ) {
        $list_current = $this->shop_view == 'grid' ? 'current' : '';
        $grid_current = $this->shop_view == 'list' ? 'current' : '';
        $output[]     = sprintf(
            '<div class="shop-view">' .
            '<span>%s</span>' .
            '<a href="#" class="grid-view mf-shop-view %s" data-view="list"><i class="icon-list4"></i></a>' .
            '<a href="#" class="list-view mf-shop-view %s" data-view="grid"><i class="icon-grid"></i></a>' .
            '</div>',
            esc_html__( 'View', 'theme' ),
            $grid_current,
            $list_current
    );
 }
    ..........
```